# Bash: Conditional Statement Without IF via Grouping Commands and Boolean Operators

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to eliminate the "if" syntax from my Bash Scripting:

```
N=
MD='title|1.md'
```

This works as expected (prints "1" and "title_1"):

```
if [ $(echo "$MD" | grep '|') ]; then N="${MD#*|}"; ID=${MD%|*}'_'$N; fi
echo "$N" ; echo "$ID"
```

This does not (prints empty):

```
[[ $(echo $MD | grep '|') ]] && $(N="${MD#*|}" ; ID=${MD%|*}'_'$N)
echo "$N" ; echo "$ID"
```

Running the script with `bash +x` it returns:

```
+ N=
++ echo 'title|1'
++ grep '|'
+ [[ -n title|1 ]]
++ N=1
++ ID=title_1
+ echo ''

+ echo ''

+ exit
```

Does anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to eliminate `if`?

Comment: I really appreciate the way Bash Script let us write code. Sometimes it is difficult to read. But it is very, very smart. In my oppinion. That's why I am poking with conditional statement by grouping commands and boolean operators.

Comment: Note, though, that `foo && bar || baz` is *not* equivalent to `if foo; then bar; else baz`, which is why replacing `if` is generally considered counterproductive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command substitution starts a subshell (and in this case the captured output would be run as a command, if there were any output). You want a command group.

```
# Skip grep as well
[[ $MD = *\|* ]] && { N=${MD#*|}; ID=${MD%|*}_$N; }
```

A regular expression can capture each side of the `|` for you, eliminating the need for the operations on `MD` later.

```
[[ $MD =~ (.*)\|(.*) ]] && { N=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; ID=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_$N; }
```

---

If you are concerned about readability, don't try to fit everything on one line.

```
if [[ $MD =~ (.*)\|(.*) ]]; then
  N=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  ID=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_$N
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, @chepner. Now I understood what's written in Bash Reference (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping): "Since the list is executed in a subshell, variable assignments do not remain in effect after the subshell completes."

Comment: And no, I'm not concerned about readability at all. I rather prefer code written in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on delimiter `|` and `read` it into two vars

```
$ MD='title|1.md' 
$ IFS=\| read -r ID N <<< "$MD"
$ [ -n "$N" ] && ID="${ID}_${N}"
$
$ echo "$N" ; echo "$ID" 
1.md
title_1.md
```